# Transformations in iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, cgpath

I've been trying to solve this for hours, without finding anything. I'm sure the solution is simple, but again, I can't seem to see it.

I'm trying to display a path that has a completely different internal coordinate system. I'm using a `CGAffineTransformation` to transform it to the screen coordinate system. Pretty simple. But 1. works and 2. doesn't display anything, and I would really like to avoid using 1. for performance reasons.

The transform matrix is `Identity` before and after the draw calls (not shown here), in case you were wondering. Also, I ran `CGContextGetPathBoundingBox` in both cases, and in 2. the affine transform doesn't seem to occur.

**1. Manually transforming the path**

```
// Get the transform
CGAffineTransform transform = box.transform;

// Add a transformed copy of the path
CGContextAddPath(offscreenContext, CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(way.path, &transform));
CGContextDrawPath(offscreenContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

**2. Trying to let iOS work its magic**

```
// Set the current transformation
CGAffineTransform transform = box.transform;
CGContextConcatCTM(offscreenContext, transform);

// Draw the path without transforming, iOS *should* do that for us
CGContextAddPath(offscreenContext, way.path);
CGContextDrawPath(offscreenContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Any idea?